# Equation in adjusted present value calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to understand an equation $V_L = V_U + \tau D \frac{r_D}{r_A}$, into which both $D=\frac{D}{V_L}V_L$ and $V_U=\frac{c_f(1-\tau)}{r_A}$ are substituted to obtain:

$$V_L=V_U+\frac{\tau r_D}{r_A}\frac{D}{V_L}V_L= \frac{V_U}{1-\tau \frac{D}{V_L} \frac{r_D}{r_A}}=\frac{c_f(1-\tau)}{r_A(1-\tau \frac{D}{V_L} \frac{r_D}{r_A})}.$$

I just can't see how the expression $V_U+\frac{\tau r_D}{r_A}\frac{D}{V_L}V_L$ is equal to $\frac{V_U}{1-\tau \frac{D}{V_L} \frac{r_D}{r_A}}.$ What am I missing?

The background to this is a finance paper titled *Reconciling DCF Valuation Methodologies* (Oded and Michel, 2007, available [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Allen_Michel/publication/265572808_Reconciling_DCF_Valuation_Methodologies/links/54b7b0ba0cf2bd04be33bbac/Reconciling-DCF-Valuation-Methodologies.pdf?origin=publication_detail)). In Equation (9) on pg. 25, the authors define the value of the levered firm, $V_L$, in terms of the value of the firm under pure equity financing, $V_U$, and the interest tax shield, $TS$:

$$V_L = V_U + TS.$$

$TS$ can also be expressed in terms of the tax rate, $\tau$, the firm's debt, $D$, and the required return to debt ($r_D$) and assets ($r_A$), respectively, as in Equation (10):

$$V_L = V_U + \tau D \frac{r_D}{r_A}.$$

$V_U$ is equivalent to the value of the firm's assets ($A$), which is the present value of the firm's after-tax cash flows ($c_f$) discounted at $r_A$ (Equation 1):

$$A=\frac{c_f(1-\tau)}{r_A}.$$

As outlined above, the part I don't understand is Equation (11), in which the authors express $V_L$ using the adjusted present value (APV) method as a function of the debt ratio $\frac{D}{V_L}$ instead of the debt dollar amount by substituting both $D=\frac{D}{V_L}V_L$ and $V_U=\frac{c_f(1-\tau)}{r_A}$ into $V_L = V_U + \tau D \frac{r_D}{r_A}$ to obtain:

$$V_L=V_U+\frac{\tau r_D}{r_A}\frac{D}{V_L}V_L= \frac{V_U}{1-\tau \frac{D}{V_L} \frac{r_D}{r_A}}=\frac{c_f(1-\tau)}{r_A(1-\tau \frac{D}{V_L} \frac{r_D}{r_A})}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if I understand it correctly that the equation is not exact. They are using that

$$1+x\approx \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Which is indeed true for small $x$ provided you discard terms of higher or equal order to $x^2$.

One has that

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+O(x^2) \; \text{ for } \; x\to 0$$

In your example, this becomes

$$\begin{eqnarray} V_L & = &V_U+\frac{\tau r_D}{r_A}\frac{D}{V_L}V_L \\ & = & V_U+\frac{\tau r_D}{r_A}\frac{D}{V_L}\left(V_U+\frac{\tau r_D}{r_A}\frac{D}{V_L}V_L\right) \\ & = & V_U+\frac{\tau r_D}{r_A}\frac{D}{V_L}V_U+\left(\frac{\tau r_D}{r_A}\frac{D}{V_L}\right)^2V_L \end{eqnarray}$$

They discard the last term because quadratic in something small.

$$\begin{eqnarray} V_L & \approx &  V_U+\frac{\tau r_D}{r_A}\frac{D}{V_L}V_U \\ & = & V_U\left(1+\frac{\tau r_D}{r_A}\frac{D}{V_L}\right) \\ & \approx & \frac{V_U}{1-\tau \frac{D}{V_L} \frac{r_D}{r_A}} \end{eqnarray}$$

And the last step is because of the approximation I explained in the beginning.